# Subtract Mean from Multidimensional Numpy-Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm currently learning about broadcasting in Numpy and in the book I'm reading ([Python for Data Analysis by Wes McKinney](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781491957653/) the author has mentioned the following example to "demean" a two-dimensional array:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(4, 3)
print(arr.mean(0))
demeaned = arr - arr.mean(0)
print(demeaned)
print(demeand.mean(0))
```

Which effectively causes the array `demeaned` to have a mean of 0.

I had the idea to apply this to an image-like, three-dimensional array:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 256, (400,400,3))
demeaned = arr - arr.mean(2)
```

Which of course failed, because according to the broadcasting rule, the trailing dimensions have to match, and that's not the case here:

```py
print(arr.shape)  # (400, 400, 3)
print(arr.mean(2).shape)  # (400, 400)
```

Now, i have gotten it to work mostly, by substracting the mean from every single index in the third dimension of the array:

```py
demeaned = np.ones(arr.shape)

for i in range(3):
    demeaned[...,i] = arr[...,i] - means

print(demeaned.mean(0))
```

At this point, the returned values are very close to zero and i think, that's a precision error. Am i actually right with this thought or is there another caveat, that i missed?

Also, this doesn't seam to be the cleanest, most '`numpy`'-way to achieve what i wanted to achieve. Is there a function or a principle that i can make use of to improve the code?

Comment: What mean are you trying to subtract? `x.mean(2)` is the 400x400 arrays of means for each pixel. Did you want a 3 element mean of each image plane instead?

Comment: No, wanted to prove the concept, in the sense that i could calculate the mean of every pixel again after the subtraction and show, that it is indeed 0 all the way through.

Comment: You can use `arr.mean(2)[:, :, np.newaxis]` to create a matching shape. See [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsIwDIbve4ocG6ijbOpB8EnEQ4YFe2gassrc09d0QpL/P3z5ZK/vwnNLWYpW4E@WHWgFlkaqcLcyKvGr5CMSVxc8TJerB3cOwfedEYclRoP7y6nfMUdiN@Hj5sHGJBw3@qb1OYh2ifF/BrG1Hw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @409_Conflict i get a shape of (400,400,1) with this approach. The same would be returned if i called `np.mean` with `keepdims=True`.

Comment: @409_Conflict thanks for the comment. Now i got your point. Didn't realize that i can subtract the resulting array!
Also thanks for the pointer to tio! I didn't know that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of numpy version 1.7.0, [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html), and several other functions, accept a tuple in their `axis` parameter. This means that you can perform the operation on the planes of the image all at once:

```
m = arr.mean(axis=(0, 1))
```

This mean will have shape `(3,)`, with one element for each plane of the image.

If you want to subtract the means of each pixel individually, you have to remember that broadcasting aligns shape tuples on the right edge. That means that you need to insert an extra dimension:

```
n = arr.mean(axis=2)
n = n.reshape(*n.shape, 1)
```

Or

```
n = arr.mean(axis=2)[..., None]
```

Comment: Ok, i got it! This is also possible, if the scalar values for each pixels are contained within an array themselves. So to call `arr.mean(2, keepdims=True)` would also lead to the correct array, that i can subtract from the original pixels-array. Is this right?

Comment: @TimHilt absolutely

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was, what i was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`np.apply_along_axis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html).

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x - np.mean(x), 2, arr)
```

Output: you get the array of the same shape where each cell is demeaned in the dimension you want (the second parameter, here it is 2).

Comment: That's nice! In fact, i like this approach a bit more, because you get rid of the  (sometimes confusing) broadcasting! Do you know how this differs in performance to the broadcasting-approach?

Comment: @TimHilt I am sorry, I don't know. You can check it with timeit module.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` in this case is slower by a factor of about 470. 2.09 S vs. 4.42mS.

Comment: @TimHilt May be for this data yes. May be for every data yes.

Comment: @TimHilt Note, it's not very large amount of data. There can be preparatory procedures (memory allocations, etc.) before the main task which waste some time. Also potentially it can work much better on computers with some features.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is a wrapper for running a python loop. It basically discards the advantages of using numpy.